# Gradle with AIDE-IDE

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aide-ide

is there a way to update version of Gradle since the one used in AIDE is version 1.

Many functions are not applicable.

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.+'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

Comment: try my answer update to 3.1.3 and add google()

Answer (score 1):

Update android build tool to the latest version:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

Also add `google()` in your buildscript. So update your existing code like below:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Francis Nduba Numbi is this help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the line:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.+'
```

if that doesnt't help, copy this line to build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```